# Do not pass or assist another vehicle to pass you by using this lane

Tags: canada, traffic, driving, definition, interpretation

Could someone confirm if "[do not pass or assist another vehicle to pass you by using this lane](https://www.alberta.ca/emergency-stopping-lane.aspx)" means:

1. Do not pass another vehicle by using this lane, and
2. Do not assist another vehicle to pass you by using this lane

Comment: The shoulder is not a lane. Why does this even need stating?

Comment: @Mazura in the linked Alberta.gov site the shoulder is called the "emergency stopping lane".  As far as they're concerned, it is a lane.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Using it to pass means passing on the right at high speed in a narrow lane full of [debris](https://www.fodcontrol.com/what-is-fod/), which is crazy.

But they're *also* saying don't use any arbitrary point on the emergency lane as a **turnout**.  A turnout is a designated "wide spot" made to allow a slower vehicle to be polite and exit the roadway for a moment to allow stacked up traffic behind them to pass.

If you want to help people pass, watch for reasonable opportunities to do so, and slow down a bit to help them position for the pass. Then once they commit, slow down more to help them get back in.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations! May I ask what FOD stands for? Thank you so much!

Comment: "Foreign Object Debris", presumably

Comment: @Maurice added a link.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: added a link to another castle? gee, Thanks.  (can't use abbreviations w/o spelling them out first)  ***Foreign Object Debris,    Foreign Object Damage***

Comment: @Mazura it's not paywalled, it's a sales site so they probably would not ever paywall it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

1. Stay off the shoulder unless there's an urgent situation or because of vehicle problems.
2. Don't move on to the shoulder to let someone pass. They should wait their turn or overtake when it's proper and safe to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations!